# error in program "removing duplicate words from string"

Tags: c++, string

I used two strings one to store words and other to store the output string. The idea is to go through character by character and whenever space is encountered , push it in the newly form string after checking whether it already exists or not.

But the code is not giving any output and I am not able to find out why.
I just want to know what I am doing wrong

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    string str1 = "";
    string word = "";
    for(auto x : str){
        if(x == ' '){
            size_t found = str1.find(word);
            if(found == string::npos){
                str1 += " " + word;
            }
        }
        else
            word += x;
    }
    cout<<str1;
}
```

Comment: `cin>>str` will only read a single word, use `std::getline` instead

Comment: Also the last word will be missing, when the input doesn't end with a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three problems here:

1. `cin >> str` will only read until the next space, so you only ever process one word. Use `std::getline` instead:

   ```
   string str;
   std::getline(cin, str);
   ```
2. You only update `str1` when you encounter a space in `str`, so you lose the last word unless the input ends with a space. You can simply append a space on the input before using it. For example put

   ```
   str.push_back(' ');
   ```

   after reading the input.
3. You don't clear `word`, so it will grow longer and longer. You can use `std::string::clear()` like so:

   ```
   if(x == ' ') {
       size_t found = str1.find(word);
       if(found == string::npos){
           str1 += " " + word;
       }
   //  VVVVVVVVVV reset word buffer after word processing of word finished
       word.clear();
   }
   ```